# how break this responses

Tags: magento2

```
{"status":{"code":200,"message":"OK","error":0,"error_messages":[]},"data":[{"product":{"9622":{"title":"12\" Square Catch Basin Grate, Decorative Wave Cast Iron","color":"Cast Iron","application":false,"status":"1","series":["Catch Basin Grates"],"image_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/abc\/pub\/static\/frontend\/abc\/default\/en_US\/Magento_Catalog\/images\/product\/placeholder\/image.jpg","url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/abc\/12-inch-square-catch-basin-grate-decorative-wave-cast-iron.html","spec_sheet_url":{"Catalog & Brochures":["PDFs\/Catalogs\/abc-Drainage-Catalog.pdf"],"Videos":["https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/PNbd2Vj31p0","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/Uwx5ZD_eloI","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/cuPKb_2KtTw","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/KdrKC_v-KQs","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/n4K0L5-Mn9E","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/anRdSVc-2X8","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/0OpO---mxwI","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/0RGr2xoMh28","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/4S0F_YuXnwU","https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/_OqFAj9xXvc"],"Technical Information":["PDFs\/Tech-Spec-Sheets\/abc-catch-basin-flow-capacities.pdf","PDFs\/Tech-Spec-Sheets\/abc-catch-basin-invert-table.pdf","PDFs\/Tech-Spec-Sheets\/abc-channel-drain-grates-flow-capacities-table.pdf"]},"related_products":[]},"10102":{"title":"12\" Square Catch Basin Grate, Decorative Wave","color":false,"application":false,"status":"1","series":["Catch Basin Grates"],"image_url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1\/abc\/pub\/static\/frontend\/abc\/default\/en_US\/Magento_Catalog\/images\/product\/placeholder\/image.jpg","url":"http
```

Comment: Use json viewer  to checkiout the result.

Comment: Use PostMan UR  oR http://jsonviewer.stack.hu

Comment: i want break this in ajax function on success and embed with html

Comment: how do you get this output?

Comment: post your ajax call

Comment: success: function (response) {
    //alert(data.error_messages);
    var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
success: function (response) {
 //alert(data.error_messages); 
 //var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
 var res = JSON.parse(response);
 console.log(res.status);
 }
```